# Java doesn't seem to utilize more than two cpus

Tags: debian, java, cpu-usage, multi-core, multi-threading

In my current setup (debian squeeze x64, 6 cpus) neither java nor apache seem to utilitze the full potential of the server. The munin monitoring shows cpu usage never exceeds the 200% mark. We ran several stress tests which raised the server load up to 80, but the cpu usage always remained low. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you double-checked that the CPU usage really is that low? It's entirely possible that Munin graphing does not work as expected and if observing the server from shell with `top` or other utilities, CPU usage is working as expected.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [this document about optimizations for running on multi-core systems](http://software.intel.com/file/22719)

There's a heap of stuff in there, everything from how to structure code to stuff like numactl for controlling processor affinity.